# Paypal live payment failed to charge customer

Tags: php, paypal

I made a PHP website which uses PayPal as a payment gateway, everything was working on sandbox mode and also I tested it myself on a live payment and it worked.

Today I got a report that a customer made a payment but it was unsuccessful, I checked my paypal log, first payment was successful but she kept trying again only to find out that she is out of funds.

Here is my log

```
[26-03-2020 10:03:50] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
[26-03-2020 10:03:51] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[26-03-2020 10:03:51] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
[26-03-2020 10:03:52] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 201
[26-03-2020 10:14:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
[26-03-2020 10:14:19] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 201
[26-03-2020 10:22:01] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
[26-03-2020 10:22:01] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 201
[26-03-2020 10:36:10] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
[26-03-2020 10:36:11] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 201
[26-03-2020 10:58:49] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
[26-03-2020 10:58:49] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 201
```

For unknown reason I think that PayPal payment status was not `approved` `$result->getState() == 'approved'`, which is the reason why it didn't take the customer to success page and save the order information.

Now my question is, how do I get the payment charged since I can't find `TransactionID` and `PayerID`? Or is there anywhere I can find this information so I can charge the customer?

I have logged in to the paypal account which is linked to the `LIVE API`, but no transaction was recorded nor pending transaction, when I looked at the developer dashboard `Live API Call History` I saw list of `PayPal Debug ID` which has today's date is there anything I can do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Editting now that logs were added to the question:

> For unknown reason i think that paypal payment status was not approved `$result->getState() == 'approved'`, which is the reason why it didn't take the customer to success page and save the order information.

The approval state will happen whenever the customer chooses to Pay within the PayPal checkout. If they don't proceed with a checkout, it will stay unapproved.  It is unlikely there is any problem with this.

> Now my question is, how do i get the payment charged since i can't find TransactionID and PayerID? Or is there anywhere i can find those information so i can charge the customer?

You can't. One of the PAYIDs must be approved by the customer for you to be able to charge them -- and if they are approved, you'll have state=approved and be able to get the PayerID from the URL they were redirected to after approval.

The sale/TransactionID is something you get in the next step of executing the payment.

---

Bottom line: If the customer was never redirected back, and you don't know their PayerID, and so never executed the payment -- and so don't have a transactionID, and the customer also doesn't have a transactionID of their own from sending the payment.  Well, there is no PayPal transaction.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the logs i was referring to

Comment: Ok those are not payment "success" logs, they are just logs of payment attempts being *initiated* (v1/payment creation)

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your question now, although I'm not sure it helps shed light on what happened to this particular customer